# problems downloading jpg images using wget

Tags: image, download, wget

I am trying to download JPG images from a website using wget. I used to be able to download, but something has changed, and I can not figure it out. Can someone help please? I have been using the following example below. Thanks

```
wget http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/BLH/450/BLH1501-450.jpg
wget http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/BLH/450/BLH1501A-450.jpg
wget http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/BLH/450/BLH1502-450.jpg
wget http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/BLH/450/BLH1503-450.jpg
```

Comment: If you open the URL in a browser you are redirected to a log-in page. Maybe you need to add some kind of authentication to your requests.

Comment: Thanks harold for answering. But if I just put in the URL in a browser, the image comes up without asking for a User, and password.  http://fastserve.horizonhobby.com/ProdInfo/BLH/450/BLH1501-450.jpg

Comment: That's because you are already logged in. I get sent to the login page when entering the URL